# vba: clipboard paste changes date to US format

Tags: vba, excel

I'm pretty sure that somewhere, someone already managed to explain this problem, but I just cant find the right answer for me.

Here is the situation:
Out of a program I copy a list to the clipboard of windows with values like this

> Something Date      Time      Something  Something ...
>
> Bla       31/03/16  02:20:22  Bla        Bla
>
> Bla       01/04/16  03:10:10  Bla        Bla

Then the VBA code finds the last free Row and does

```
.PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
```

The Result in Excel is

> Bla 31/03/2016 20:22,0 Bla Bla
>
> Bla 04.01.2016 10:10,0 Bla Bla

And that's not what it should be.

I tried `.PasteSpecial Format:="Unicode-Text"` with the same result

I cant get `Paste:=xlValues` and so on to work. (1004)

The best part is, if I right click (or ctrl+v) the sheet and past it, EVERYTHING just magically appears the right way.

> Bla 31.03.2016 02:20:22 Bla Bla
>
> Bla 01.04.2016 03:10:10 Bla Bla

So I assume I'm doing something very stupid and I just need to find the vba expression to make it right.

Can someone please help me.

Comment: Just a small hint - when everything appears the right way when you do simple commands - then use macro recorder and edit the code with it.

Comment: Yes that was the first thing I did! Unfortunately the result was the same. The recorder gives out the code: ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial Format:="Unicode-Text", link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False, NoHTMLFormatting:=True

Comment: How about ".PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats"

Comment: Maybe I'm doing it wrong. But I get Error 1004. ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats

Comment: activesheet.range("A1").pastespecial paste:=xlPasteFormats

Comment: Nope. Still 1004 PasteSpecial method couldnt be applied to the range object

Answer (score 0):

Since there doesn't seem to be an easy answer to this particular problem I wrote myself a workaround.

This workaround is only necessary if you paste from windows clipboard and you have a lot of different data. Excel to excel has different possibilities.

```
Dim iDay As Integer
Dim iMonth As Integer
Dim iYear As Integer
Dim currRow As Integer
Dim iName As String

'Change date to correct date because of xl bug
currRow = 3
iName = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("YourSheet").Cells(currRow, 4)

Do While iName <> ""
    If InStr(1, ThisWorkbook.Sheets("YourSheet").Cells(currRow, 2), "/", vbTextCompare) <> 0 Then
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("YourSheet").Cells(currRow, 2).Replace "/", "."
    Else
        iDay = Split(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("YourSheet").Cells(currRow, 2), ".")(1)
        iMonth = Split(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("YourSheet").Cells(currRow, 2), ".")(0)
        iYear = Split(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("YourSheet").Cells(currRow, 2), ".")(2)
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("YourSheet").Cells(currRow, 2) = DateSerial(iYear, iMonth, iDay)
    End If
currRow = currRow + 1
iName = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("YourSheet").Cells(currRow, 4)
Loop
```